# How to configure UITableView inside custom UITableViewCell in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, custom-cell

I have a `layout` in which I will have 2 `UITableViews` with custom `cells`. The second `UITableView` must be inside the first.

My question is: how to delegate second `UITableView`?

Can I delegate both to my `ViewController`? In that case it will use the same methods and I have to find out which `UITableView` is managed right now.

Or I have to delegate it inside custom `UITableViewCell` of the first `UITableView`?

Any recommendations are appreciated.

EDIT: I don't know how to implement solutions here, because I have `Storyboard`. Inside my current `UIViewController` I set `delegate` and `dataSource` of the first `UITableView` to my View Controller.

My problem is that I don't know how to set the same properties of the second Table View (which will be inside `UITableViewCell`). I can not set them to `UITableViewCell` (IB does not allow that).

Where and how to set then in the IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just check table condition for every delegate method

Use this code to register custom cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView == self.yourFirstTable)
{
    CustomCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellModifier"];
    // your code
}
else
{
    // second table cell code
}
return cell;
}



 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   { 
        if(tableView == self.yourFirstTable)
        {
             // first tableView number of row return
        }
        else
        {
             // second table number of row return
        }   
   }
```

And create prototype cell in `TableView`

[image]

And Set CellReusableId like this way

[image]

Comment: Sorry I already know that. My problem is how to configure `datasource` and `delegate` of second `UITableView` - which object must be configured for them.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I thought that this can be the solution but I was not sure that it will work. 10x. I will try and if it is ok I will accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry @Dharmesh Dhorajiya, but I miss something - where to set delegate for the second `UITableView` - on ViewController, or on the first `UITableView`. Also where to set outlet for the second `UITableView`?

Comment: I understand the answer and implemented it, but the second table does not spin right - I have 2 times section 0 instead of section 0 and section 1 - where can I make a mistake? Both `UITableView` are delegated and set data source inside `Storyboard`.

Comment: try this way `if(tableView == self.yourFirstTable)
    {
        // first tableView number of row return
        if(indexPath.section==0)
        {
            //1 section code
        }
        else if (indexPath.section==1){
            // 2 section code
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // second table number of row return
        if(indexPath.section==0)
        {
            //1 section code
        }
        else if (indexPath.section==1){
            // 2 section code
        }
    }
` @new2ios

Answer (score 3):

A far better solution would be to abstract the DataSource and Delegate implementations away from your view controller so that they can be personalised per tableview as required (please note that the code is taken from the *objc.io* article [Lighter View Controllers](http://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/lighter-view-controllers/).

E.g.

```
@implementation ArrayDataSource

- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    return items[(NSUInteger)indexPath.row];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    configureCellBlock(cell,item);
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Then you could utilise it as follows:

```
void (^configureCell)(PhotoCell*, Photo*) = ^(PhotoCell* cell, Photo* photo) {
   cell.label.text = photo.name;
};
photosArrayDataSource = [[ArrayDataSource alloc] initWithItems:photos
                                                cellIdentifier:PhotoCellIdentifier
                                            configureCellBlock:configureCell];
self.tableView.dataSource = photosArrayDataSource;
```

The same process could be followed with the UITableViewDelegate implementations to provide you with a very clean, separated and de-coupled code base. Your requirement for two tableviews will then be intrinsically easier to implement.

Comment: I agree with you but I will approve other answer because I implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

```
  For identifying two table view data source and delegate method is,better to set tag for the table views.
```

Set this below coding in your tableview delegates method.

```
 if(tableView.tag==0)
 {
 }
 else
 {
 }
```

Also you can vary this by assigning different name to these table view.

```
 if(tableView==FirstTableView)
 {
 }
 else
 {
 }
```